# Looping through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the array of objects called res and am trying to loop through and organize the objects based on having one href, one method, and in some cases multiple schema, as with: 
`href: '/questions/{id}'`

My issue is when I have multiple schema, if the current object I am in has '$schema' I want to check if the next object in the array also has '$schema'. If it does then I want to label the current schema object, requestSchema and the next object will be called responseSchema. But if the next object does not contain '$schema' then the current object will be labeled responseSchema.

I want to take res and turn it into

```
[{
        "resource": "/questions",
        "verb": "GET",
        "schemaResponse": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [{
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "question": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "enum": [
                                    "Favourite programming language?"
                                ]
                            },
                            "published_at": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "enum": [
                                    "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z"
                                ]
                            },
                            "url": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "enum": [
                                    "/questions/1"
                                ]
                            },
                            "choices": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": [{
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "choice": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "enum": [
                                                "Javascript"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "url": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "enum": [
                                                "/questions/1/choices/1"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "votes": {
                                            "type": "number",
                                            "enum": [
                                                2048
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "choice",
                                        "url",
                                        "votes"
                                    ],
                                    "additionalProperties": false
                                }]
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "question",
                            "published_at",
                            "url",
                            "choices"
                        ],
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    }]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "data"
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "resource": "/questions/{id}",
        "verb": "GET",
        "schemaRequest": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id"
            ]
        },
        "schemaResponse": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "question": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "Favourite programming language?"
                    ]
                },
                "published_at": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z"
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "/questions/1"
                    ]
                },
                "choices": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [{
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "choice": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "enum": [
                                    "Javascript"
                                ]
                            },
                            "url": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "enum": [
                                    "/questions/1/choices/1"
                                ]
                            },
                            "votes": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "enum": [
                                    2048
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "choice",
                            "url",
                            "votes"
                        ],
                        "additionalProperties": false
                    }]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "question",
                "published_at",
                "url",
                "choices"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }

    }

]
```

Everything works except for in the case of needing to have a request schema and a response schema.

```
const lodash = require('lodash');

var res =  [ 
    { href: '/questions' },
    { method: 'GET' },
    { '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
      type: 'object',
      properties: { data: [Object] },
      required: [ 'data' ] },
    { href: '/questions/{id}',
      hrefVariables: { element: 'hrefVariables', content: [Object] } },
    { method: 'GET',
      headers: { element: 'httpHeaders', content: [Object] } },
    { '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
      type: 'object',
      properties: { id: [Object] },
      required: [ 'id' ] },
    { '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
      type: 'object',
      properties: 
        { question: [Object],
          published_at: [Object],
          url: [Object],
          choices: [Object] },
      required: [ 'question', 'published_at', 'url', 'choices' ] } ]


    var arr = [];
    var arrFinal = [];
    var result = {};
    for (var key = 0; key < res.length; key++) {
        console.log(res[key]);
        console.log(key);

        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            //console.log((lodash.has(res[key], 'href')));
            //console.log((lodash.has(res[key-1], '$schema')));   
            if ((lodash.has(arr[i], 'href'))) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ((lodash.has(res[key], '$schema')) && (lodash.has(res[key-1], '$schema'))) {
                console.log('here');
                result.schemaResponse = res[key];
                result = lodash.omit(result, ['headers', 'properties', 'hrefVariables', 'required', 'href', 'method']);
                break;


        }

        if((found === true) && (lodash.has(res[key], '$schema'))) {

            var result = {};   
            console.log('there') 
            var combinedKeys = arr.reduce(function(a, item) {
                Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {
                     if(key === 'href'){
                        result.resource = item[key];
                    }
                    if(key === 'method'){
                        result.verb = item[key];
                    } else {
                        result[key] = item[key];
                    }        

                });
                return result;
            }, {});
            arr = [];

            if((lodash.has(res[key+1], '$schema'))){
                result.schemaRequest = res[key];
            } else {
                result.schemaResponse = res[key];
                result = lodash.omit(result, ['headers', 'properties', 'hrefVariables', 'required', 'href', 'method']);
                arrFinal.push(result);
                result = {};
            }


        }

         else {
            console.log('hmmm');
            var object = res[key];
            arr.push(object); 

        }
    }

    var string = JSON.stringify(arrFinal, null, '  ')
    console.log(arrFinal)
```

Comment: Your question was a little unclear (I'd suggest proofreading it again and breaking up some of the run-on sentences).  Are you saying that when you evaluate `if ((lodash.has(res[key], '$schema')) && (lodash.has(res[key-1], '$schema')))` the value `res[key-1]` is always undefined?.  So basically the 2nd *if* block never executes?

Comment: @jusopi Yes that is exactly what I am saying. I am trying to go to either the next or previous object in the array and check if it has '$schema'. But am not sure why what I have does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: When key = 0 k-1 = -1 which is out of bounds.  Similarly, when key = length -1 (the last element in the array) key + 1 = length which is out of bounds.  Adding if checks for these two situations should fix this issue.

Comment: @nurdyguy would not checking those cases cause the value to always be undefined though? Also where should I implement those checks?

Comment: can you please explain "what" you want to do and leave the "how's" out because they're obviously not working? Let others come up with the working how.

Comment: @BekimBacaj I hope my edits helped explain the issue a little more if not I can open a chat with you and we can discuss further.

Comment: You know they are invalid values so why would you check them?  if(key > 0) then check the key - 1, if(key -1 < length) then check the key + 1 value.

Comment: @nurdyguy No i totally understand that logic, I'm just saying would not doing that check make it so that in all cases it would return undefined?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by that but I would say two things.  1.  You cannot check those values because they are guaranteed to be invalid.  2.  If skipping those two values causes other problems elsewhere then there is something very very wrong with the overall logic of your code.

Comment: `I want to check if the next object also has '$schema' and if so after it labels the current schema request and the later response.`
is an unfinished thought and sentence.  and after it does that. - What?

Comment: Okay let me rephrase my question, you said that I should exclude checking those values, if i don't exclude checking those values could that be the reason that when you check the valid values that they are coming back undefined.

Comment: @BekimBacaj if the next object has '$schema' then the current schema is Request and the next schema is Response.

Comment: I made changes to the question I hope this should make helping easier thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this:

> My issue is when I have multiple schema, if the current object I am in has '$schema' I want to check if the next object in the array also has '$schema'. If it does then I want to label the current schema object, requestSchema and the next object will be called responseSchema. But if the next object does not contain '$schema' then the current object will be labeled responseSchema.

and this (from my comment on your question):

> Your question was a little unclear (I'd suggest proofreading it again and breaking up some of the run-on sentences). Are you saying that when you evaluate if ((lodash.has(res[key], '$schema')) && (lodash.has(res[key-1], '$schema'))) the value res[key-1] is always undefined?. So basically the 2nd if block never executes

Here is some pseudo-code to work into your code:

```
 for ( var nIdx, crnt, next, key = 0, m = res.length; key < m; key++ ){
     crnt = res[ key ]
     next = res[ key + 1 ]

     //do your checking here based on the existence of 'next'
     if (next){ .... }
}
```

I'd test this on a simple loop and log the values of `crnt` and `next` to see if you're actually getting the expected results.  If they are as expected, you can adjust your code to use those values instead of trying to access them dynamically with `res[ key ]` further down in your code.

I dunno, what the issue really is with your code, but this will be more readable at the least and will probably illuminate your error.

Comment: Is k supposed to be key?

Comment: yep, typo. it's fixed